# How to replace odd/even chars in string with spaces in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

If given a string like "go to med!" how do I replace just the even characters for example? The problem is that while my code takes care of the first word, the space between the words counts as a character itself and messes up replacements in the second word with the first letter of the second word becoming classified as even.

Here is my attempt

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "go to med!";
    String alphabetS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char currChar = s.charAt(i);

        int idx = alphabetS.indexOf(currChar);
        if (idx != -1) 
        if (i%2==1)

            {
        sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sb);

}
```

This gives output "g+ +o m+d!" 
(second letter being correctly replaced by + for being even, but the first letter of the second word should not be replaced as "first" is not "even". 
How to make the index to ignore white spaces?

Preferably the answer should not contain arrays, only Char and String methods.

Comment: Split the input on the space, process each work individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply split the input on the space and process each work individually.  You could then use a `StringJoiner` to piece together the result, for example...

```
String s = "go to med!!";
String alphabetS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

String[] words = s.split(" ");
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        char currChar = sb.charAt(i);

        int idx = alphabetS.indexOf(currChar);
        if (idx != -1) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
            }
        }

    }
    sj.add(sb.toString());
}
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

which outputs

```
g* t* m*d!!
```

> could this be done without using arrays - just with char and string methods?

Instead of relying on `i`, you need a separate counter, which tracks which point your up to and which can be used to ignore invalid characters, for example

```
String s = "go to med!!";
String alphabetS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    char currChar = sb.charAt(i);

    int idx = alphabetS.indexOf(currChar);
    if (idx != -1) {
        if (counter % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("!!");
            sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
        }
        counter++;
    }

}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

which still outputs

```
g* t* m*d!!
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it! But,as I've asked in the OP: could this be done without using arrays - just with char and string methods?

Comment: You like to make life difficult for yourself don't you

Comment: haha, its the best way to get better ;) On a serious note, the task was set as a char/string exercise, so using arrays would be almost cheating I feel.

Comment: You're still only dealing with `String` and `char`, you're just breaking the problem down to small, more manageable chunks, but it's your problem not mine ;). Now you have at least two ways you might make it work

Answer (score 1):

this gives: `g* t* m*d*`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "go to med!";
    int realindex=0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char currChar = s.charAt(i);
        if ((currChar != ' '))
        {
            if (realindex%2==1) {
                currChar = '*';
            }
            realindex++;
        }
        sb.append(currChar);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: `!` isn't considered a valid character for the purpose of the conversion, the OP has a list of valid characters they want to be able to replace, although the use of a second counter is a good idea ;)

Comment: Ha. I was wondering what that alphabetS string was for. Then instead of the != '' it would be a check if the currChar exists in that alphabetS string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a thousand different ways to accomplish your goal, but assuming you want to keep using your solution, here is what you could do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "go to med!! goodbye cruel world";
    String alphabetS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);


    for (int i = 0,relativePosition=0; i < s.length(); i++,relativePosition++) {
        char currChar = s.charAt(i);

        if(currChar == ' '){relativePosition=-1;continue;}

        int idx = alphabetS.indexOf(currChar);
        if (idx != -1)
            if (relativePosition % 2 == 1)
                sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

that prints

```
g* t* m*d!! g*o*b*e c*u*l w*r*d
```

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you very much for posting!

Comment: You're welcome! But be sure to understand WHY it works, that's what makes the difference in your learning path

Answer (score 0):

What about introducing flag about even state of letter?

```
boolean isEven=false;
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    char currChar = s.charAt(i);
    int idx = alphabetS.indexOf(currChar);
    if (idx != -1)
        if(isEven){
            isEven=false;
            sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
        }else {
            isEven = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Really appreciate you input guys (and/or gals:))